# How to commit a part of a file in SourceTree for Hg on Mac

Tags: macos, mercurial, tortoisehg, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree 1.9.3.1 with Mercurial on Mac OSX 10.9.3.

I come from TortoiseHg on Windows, where it is possible to select the exact lines I want to commit within a file. Any unselected lines are available for selection on the next commit.

Sadly TortoiseHg isn't supported on Mac. How can I make SourceTree behave in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. According to [TortoiseHG Download page](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/download/index.html) Installer [packages are available](https://s3.amazonaws.com/kiln-tortoisehg-nightlies/index.htm) (slightly outdated, yes)
2. [Wiki-page for Mac-users](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/developers/MacOSX) give some additional information about installing TortoiseHG
3. In order to commit only hunks of files, you have to have enabled [Record Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RecordExtension) on top of pure Mercurial

Comment: Thanks for explaining that hg record is the feature I've been using. I thought it was something in the THg UI